# Unit test using moq to an api rest core

Tags: c#, .net, api, moq

I am doing an unit test with moq, mi code is about an api. I already done the service and repository, but i get error when i want to return the result.
I am new in moq and i can´t understand fine how it is the use with moq.

**This is my repository**

```
    {
        Task<List<Course>> FindAll();
        Task<Course?> FindById(int id);
        Task<List<Course>> FindByIds(List<int> ids);
        void Insert(Course Course);
        Task Delete(int id);
        void Update(Course Course);
        Task<int> Save();
    }
```

**This is my service**

```
public class CourseService: ICourseService {
  private readonly ICourseRepository _courseRepository;
  private readonly IMapper _mapper;
  private ICourseRepository @object;
  private IMapper object1;

  public CourseService(ICourseRepository courseRepository, IMapper mapper) {
    _courseRepository = courseRepository;
    _mapper = mapper;
  }

  public CourseService(ICourseRepository @object) {
    this.@object = @object;
  }

  public CourseService(IMapper object1) {
    this.object1 = object1;
  }

  public async Task < List < CourseDto >> FindAll() {
    List < Course > course = await _courseRepository.FindAll();
    return _mapper.Map < List < Course > , List < CourseDto >> (course);
  }

  public async Task < CourseDto ? > FindById(int id) {
    Course ? course = await _courseRepository.FindById(id);
    return course == null ? null : _mapper.Map < Course, CourseDto > (course);
  }

}
}
```

**This is my testing**

```
public class CourseServiceTest {
  private readonly CourseService _sut;
  private readonly Mock < ICourseRepository > _courseRepoMock = new Mock < ICourseRepository > ();
  private readonly Mock < IMapper > _mapperMock = new Mock < IMapper > ();

  public CourseServiceTest() {
    _sut = new CourseService(_courseRepoMock.Object);
    //_sut = new CourseService(_mapperMock.Object);
  }

  [Fact]
  public async Task GetAllCoursesById() {
    //Arrange
    var courseId = 1;
    var courseName = "Esta es una prueba";
    var courseDescription = "Description";
    var courseDuration = 34.5;
    var courseRating = 34.5;
    var courseDeleted = false;
    var courseCreatedBy = 1;
    var courseUpdatedBy = 1;

    var courseDto = new CourseDto {
      Name = courseName,
        Description = courseDescription,
        Duration = courseDuration,
        Rating = courseRating,
        Deleted = courseDeleted,
        CreatedBy = courseCreatedBy,
        UpdatedBy = courseUpdatedBy
    };
    _courseRepoMock.Setup(x => x.FindById(courseId)).ReturnsAsync(CourseDto);

    //Act
    var course = await _sut.FindById(courseId);

    //Assert

    Assert.Equal(courseId, course.Id);
    Assert.Equal(courseDescription, course.Description);
    Assert.Equal(courseDuration, course.Duration);
    Assert.Equal(courseRating, course.Rating);
    Assert.Equal(courseDeleted, course.Deleted);
    Assert.Equal(courseCreatedBy, course.CreatedBy);
    Assert.Equal(courseUpdatedBy, course.UpdatedBy);
  }
}
```

**I need the testing for the both methods, *FindAll* and *FindById* **

Comment: I don't see the point of mocking REST APIs during unit test stage, better off just doing without and the effort and perform the real tests during integration testing.

Comment: I would like to know how i could do integration testing also, i would thank if you could help me please.

Comment: Well that's a new question, feel free to post it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! *I already done the service and repository, but i get error when i want to return the result* < Which line throws what error?

Comment: By the way why do you need these: ` private ICourseRepository @object;` and
  `private IMapper object1;` ? `_courseRepository` and `_mapper` aren't enough?